# Passing the name of an url to ma

Tags: html, web-access

I have the following command[image]

How to circonvent this weird comportment. Perhaps, it is not possible to open a pdf file from mathematica. But this is not the full problem.

Comment: Why did't you use string for the url?

Comment: Because the output open nothing

Comment: I can open pdf file in browser with a url in a string wrapped in function `Hyperlink`, I still cannot get your point doing that.

Comment: I hust have seen the error Unknown string escape \m .

Comment: The url must start with `http://`.  Then -1 for posting a picture rather than code text. I'll retract the downvote after you post the code.

Comment: Not all Url begin with http://

Comment: @cyrille.piatecki If it doesn't start with http:// then it starts with another protocol like ftp://, sftp://, https://... there is no URL that doesn't start with a protocol as in your image. (Your browser may be forgiving however, and assume the protocol if it's missing.)

Comment: The severe lack of effort put forward in this question is why I downvoted.  If you can't even bother to finish the title of question..

Comment: chuy ok the question was stupid, but the title was correct. ma is often used as an acronym for Mathematica

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Hyperlink["description", 
"http://coco-m.web.lynchburg.edu/multiplicative calculus.pdf"]
```

Evaluate the link, then click on description.